# How to use Rest Api in kaa with version 0.10.0 with document in ver 0.9

Tags: kaa

i try to use rest api in kaa ver 0.10.0 but document is empty https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/
I use document in ver 0.9 but something not work.How i can reference rest api with kaa ver 0.10.0

Answer (score 0):

I used this API http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Admin+REST+API#AdminRESTAPI-Getuserprofile  and was successfully able to use it. Please specify the specific problem you are facing?
Edit: and dont forget to check the api using PostMan if you find any issue.

Comment: i run this request: /kaaAdmin/rest/api/endpointGroups/{applicationId} and it return 404 error: "The requested item was not found!"

Answer (score 0):

Please share the error msg that you are getting. Mostly it's a case of incorrect appender config or field name mismatch with those mentioned in your DB. I was facing following errors with REST log appender but was able to solve them as mentioned below:

Error 500: I found two errors with my configuration of RestLogAppender in the admin panel. First, I had put http:// before my host. Had to remove the same. Second, I should have mentioned Relative URI path starting and ending with a forward slash /.

Error 400: I had given slightly different names to the JSON fields in the Django models. The sequence of the fields did not matter but the name of fields did matter.

Comment: i run this request: /kaaAdmin/rest/api/endpointGroups/{applicationId} and it return 404 error: "The requested item was not found!"

Comment: Hi, @DucNguyen, can you provide server logs when you got this error. Are you sure that you specify right applicationToken not applicationId in your REST API path?

Answer (score 0):

The Kaa 0.10.0 documentation server REST API uses JS scripts that are hosted on third-party servers. Unfortunately, those servers are now down and that is why the REST API documentation page is rendered empty at the moment.

Kaa team has already prepared a fix for this. The respective JS files will be hosted along with the documentation. But, this requires some additional work to be done before the updated documentation become available.